# Error: HTTP 400 Unable to create record: Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address

Tags: twilio

Utilizo las credenciales que me provee **Twilio** en el *dashboard*:

[image: dashboard]

Corroborando que sean las credenciales *live*:

[image: tokens]

También corroboro que el número que quiero usar sea el que está confirmado en **sandbox**.

[image: sandbox]

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```php
$twilio_number = "+51XXXXXX618";
$client = new \Twilio\Rest\Client(
    'account_sid',
    'auth_token'
);
$message = $client->messages->create(
    "whatsapp:+51XXXXXX148",
    [
        // "from" => "whatsapp:+14155238886",
        "from" => "whatsapp:".$twilio_number,
        "body" => "Prueba de envio de msj"
    ]
);
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error (código en php):

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

El [error 400](https://codigoshttp.com/400/) significa que la petición no se ha realizado correctamente. Asegúrate de que los nombres de los parámetros son los correctos. Prueba a cambiar `from` por `userid`.
Si sigue sin funcionar, comprueba la documentación de la API para asegurarte de cuales son los parámetros requeridos.

Aquí tienes una lista de todos los errores HTTP https://codigoshttp.com/

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás ya cumpliste este paso, pero como no está indicado en la pregunta supongo que es algo que falta.

Twilio solo conoce los número que se conectan con él explícitamente.
Primero el usuario debe enviar al número de twilio el code. En tu caso es "join aloud-island"

Te responderá con un mensaje que confirma la conexión. A partir de allí y durante 72 horas podrás comunicarte con el código en ambas direcciones.